# Static and dynamic allocation memory addressing?

Tags: c++, c++11, dynamic-memory-allocation, static-memory-allocation

I initialized an array in C++ using both static and dynamic allocation.

```
// dynamic allocation... len is input by user.
int *data = new int [len];
// print memory address
cout<< &data<<endl;
cout<< &data[0]<<endl;
// static allocation...
int *arr1[10];
// print memory address
cout<< &arr1<<endl;
cout<< &arr1[0]<<endl;
```

I expected that &data and &data[0] to return the same memory address as they point to the location of the first element of the array. However, I obtained the following results :

> 0x7fffb9f3dd40
>
> 0x24c6010
>
> 0x7fffb9f3dcf0
>
> 0x7fffb9f3dcf0

This seemed to work as expected for arr1. Please can some one explain this? What am I missing?

Comment: `int *data` data here is a pointer; taking its pointer results in a pointer to a pointer. `int *arr1[10]` arr1 is an array (of pointers); taking its pointer results in a pointer to the first element of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data` and `arr1` are very different here: `data` is a pointer to an `int` array, `arr1` is an `int*` array. As such `&data` is the address of the pointer to the array, not the address of the first element of the array.

Comment: So data would point to the address which stores the location of the first element of the array? I mean to say that data and &data[0] would show the same thing? and &data would show the location of the pointer?

Comment: Sorry, I edited it a bit while you were typing. I hope it's still right!

Comment: The value of `data` is a pointer to the first element of the array. `&data` is the address of that variable.`&data[0]` is the address of the first element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code

```
cout<< &data<<endl;
```

Prints the address of the pointer variable, not it's content obtained with `new`.

Answer (score 0):

`&data` returns the address of the `data` variable itself.
`&data[0]` returns the address of the first element `data` points to.

Answer (score 0):

data is pointing to an address on the heap, but &data is pointing to data and that lives on the stack.

Comment: "heap" and "stack" are not defined in C++ in the way you describe. Dynamic allocation is from the free-store and data on the "stack" could alternatively be in a register or optimized out.

Comment: Ok, I was possibly using the terms in practice.